# What to do when the user enables or disables the iCloud support in the app Settings Bundle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud, uimanageddocument

I am targeting **iOS7** and I use **iCloud** with an `UIManagedDocument`. I would like to know what to do in these two cases:

1) ***First case: App first launch***

It's the first launch, when we do not know yet if the user wants to use iCloud or not and we should assume he doesn't want to use it until we ask him. Once we'll find out, his choice will be stored in the app Settings Bundle and he will be able to change his mind later.

When my app launch, the first view that appears triggers the UIManagedDocument init with `[[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url]`. It does this because it should know how many rows it has to display in its table.

At this point, it is the first launch, and I still have to ask to the user, I assume he does not want to use iCloud so the UIManagedDocument is initialized without the `persistentStoreOptions` set (`NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey` and `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey`).

The file is then created on the disk with

```
[UIManagedDocument saveToURL: URL 
            forSaveOperation: UIDocumentSaveForCreating 
           completionHandler: ^(BOOL success){

            if(success){
              //Do something with the document
            }

           }];
```

then the view appears. Since it is the first launch, I should ask the user if he wants to use iCloud or not.

I show an `UIAlertView` from `[viewDidAppear:animated]`

If he answers "***NO***", everything is already ok. But what should I do if he says "***YES***"??

Should I close the `UIManagedDocument` and migrate the DB or is it enough to set the `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey` and `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey` in the document's `persistentStoreOptions`?

2) ***Second case: a couple of days later the user changes his mind***

The user did choose to enable iCloud but after some day he changes his mind. He switches to NO the iCloud option in the app settings bundle. When the app launches I check for a change in this option and I find that it has switched from YES to NO. As I understood from the hints I got on SO, the correct path should be to display an UIAlertView asking him if he wants:

a) Keep the documents on the device

b) Delete the documents from the device

c) Keep using iCloud

What should i do for the options a) and b)? 
A DB migration for option a) and recreate the DB from zero for option b)?

Comment: Q1- No it's not OK to simply open the file using iCloud options. You have to use the persistentstorecoordinators migratePersistentStore API.

Comment: Q2- in your case Make sure those specific choices are relevant, if not then change them. If the user has no visibility of Documents then they may be a bit confused. Perhaps something like 'Keep existing data', 'Remove existing data', 'Keep using iCloud'

Comment: Q2a - not only do you have to migrate to a local only store, but what to do about the stuff already in iCloud? Do you need to remove it or run the risk of some merge clash if the user later decides to once again use iCloud! Messy huh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're using the term "migration" is a little confusing, as incrementing the Core Data model from one version to a new one is also called migration. I assume you're just talking about "migrating" from iCloud to local only or vice versa.

In your first case, I wouldn't create the `UIManagedDocument` until the user has made a choice. If the user wants to use iCloud, all you have to do is take that and open it and you don't have to worry about closing/removing the local document (which is now pointless).

In the second case, if the user chooses option A, copy the file from iCloud to local, then remove it from iCloud. Option B means "remove from iCloud, I don't want it anymore". If you still want to continue using Core Data locally, create a new document for it. C, of course, would do nothing, just dismiss the alert.

Comment: Yes, I am using the term "migrating" meaning from iCloud to local only or vice versa. Unfortunately I have not the option to create the UIManagedDocument only when the user has made his choice unless I write some "dirty code" to check if it is the first launch of the app and the I set to 1 the rows in the table rows and I tricky the cell but it doesn't look an elegant solution to me.

Comment: I wouldn't check if it's the first launch, I would check if a file exists. If not, ask the user to use iCloud and copy the file. If it already exists, just use that file. You'll only have to check once. Upon creating/copying from iCloud you reload your table and you're all set. The user can't use the table before s/he makes the choice between iCloud/local anyway.

Comment: I thought about it. Unfortunately there is no way to not create the UIManagedDocument until the user made his choice. Main reason, and this is clear in Apple docs, is that one should ask the user if he wants to use iCloud or not only if iCloud is available on the device. A user could start the app the first time with iCloud not enabled, the app then will not get the iCloud token but still should let the user create his data. Only when iCloud will be available I should ask him if he wants to use iCloud and If he'll answer YES I'll have to move the DB from local only to the cloud.

Comment: @NicolaPrada: Correct, but that's really the same as "the user did not initially allow iCloud, but changed his mind later". You would have to account for that anyway, so maybe it's easier to do it that way. However, deleting a document that you just created doesn't feel right to me, so I would probably not create it until I know I need it, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Typically there are two places to check whether iCloud settings have changed and/or to check or open any files:
1) in the AppDelegate method application:didfinishlaunchingwithoptions, and
2) in the AppDelegate method applicationwillenterforeground

In addition if you register for iCloud account change notifications you can respond to them.

This allows you to organise things before your view starts trying to display any core data items.  Opening or Migrating a file may take some time so you may have to display some other activity indicator view while this is being performed.

I would not create the document in the view that displays data because the call to open the document is performed asynchronously and until the completion handler runs you don't know when it's going to complete. Rather you should use the completion handler to launch this view because then you know it's safe to start accessing the core data objects.

More details on how to achieve [UIManagedDocument & iCloud Integration](http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/) here.